# Editing a database entry via jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql-update

This query gives me a list from the database

```
while($res=mysql_fetch_array($temp)){                   
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td id='copyme'>".$res['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=''>Edit</a></td>";                        
}
echo "</tr>";
```

By clicking the edit i want the name to be written in this input box so i can update or delete it, the sql update query works once the name is on the box, my only problem is to get the name there once i click edit.

```
 <label>Template name:</label> <input id="temp_edit" type="text" name="tempname" />
```

How can id do this via jquery? or is there a better way?

Comment: i thinks better to have it in isset than having the condition that if the edit button is click it will execute.

Comment: Your selectors have issues, id's must be unique, so that `copyme` is useless, also, your A has a difficult identifier, add a class to it, like `class="edit"`. Then just use `$('.edit').click(function(){ $("#temp_name").val($(this).prev('.edit').text()) });`

Answer (score 3):

Use `copyme` as a `class`, not an `id` because you will be having more than one of that element if you have a list from database, then try this:

```
$('#yourTable').on('click', 'a', function(){
    var copyValue = $('.copyme', $(this).closest('tr')).text();
    $('#temp_edit').val(copyValue);
});
```

Comment: everything looks good here. One thing, he'll get the name and the `Edit` text from the A also using that selector. And there's no reason to create a variable that's only going to be used once imo.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.I think it wont get the `Edit` text since i only select text from `td` with class `copyme` and the `Edit` `td` dont have that class. As for the variable, I implemented it that way so that the OP can better understande the code and it might confuse him if I put it on one line, as I assumed that the OP might be new in JQuery because of his question. :)

Comment: Fair enough, read too quick and didn't pay attention to you using a parent element to search under there. my bad. yep yep looks good elsewise.

Comment: Impressive @NixR.Eyes..you are improving on spoken english..SO is helpful to you.. :P

Comment: @NixR.Eyes the aswer above is not working, i even tried putting the copied text on a div, still no results, here is my jquery    `function edittemplate() {var copyValue = $('.copyme', $(this).closest('tr')).text();$('#temp_edit').val(copyValue);}` and the php `echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='edittemplate()'>Edit</a></td>"; `

Comment: @jobkwemoi could you please show an example of rendered html, or fiddle maybe. :)